# "Customer email is required" customer creating in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, api, soap

While I was trying to create a customer in magenton using SOAP api It was showing this error.

> Customer email is required

I have set the customer email. Does anyone have any idea whats the wrong I am doing here?

Actully I have used the [magja](https://github.com/magja/magja) and

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
String mEmailString = new String("user@test.com");     
customer.setFirstName("User");
customer.setLastName("Shop");
customer.setPassword("12345678");

customer.setGroupId(1);
customer.setGender(Customer.Gender.MALE);
customer.setEmail(mEmailString);    
customer.setStoreId(1);
customer.setWebsiteId(1);                   

remoteServiceFactory.getCustomerRemoteService().save(customer);//here the error occurs
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Marius I have added code in the question.

Comment: Hi , i have same problem did you find any solution ?

Comment: @mahdi nope still no solution! :(

Comment: Is this still a recent problem or did you solve it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module, outdated question (no response from creator since April 1st)

Comment: yah the api is not being updated so, we decided not to use it for our purpose.